# How to implement PINCH ZOOM on a RelativeLayout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have an XML and the total XML is to be pinch zoomedl. The XML has ImageView, TextView, ExpandabeleListView and so on.. Now i want to make all the content in that XML such as the image, text and the expandable listview must be zoomed.. and the zoomed content must be scrolled vertically and horizontally when the totlat xml is piched zoomed.